# All that combine or all that combined?

Tags: tense, plural-forms, singular-vs-plural

> I don't want to make the same mistake. Therefore, I did my homework on my potential colleges. Moreover, I have my ultimate goal of becoming a research dentist. All that combine, my next obligation is to find a new college where I could embark upon my dream.

In this sentence, is usage of 'all that combine' correct or 'all that combines' or 'all that combined'?

Answer (score 1):

"All that combined" is the right one. However,

If "all that combined" is used without a preposition "with", it doesn't serve the purpose of using the word "combined".

If you have to use the word "combined', I would suggest using it as follows,

All that combined with a desire to find the best suitable college for my dream, I decided to visit a few colleges to get a professional advice from professors and students.

It is just a suggestion because using only "all that combined" as a conjunctive adverb, it sounds a bit awkward.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

'All that combined' is the better of the two, but even better may be 'With all of that combined,'...